# Angular JS to validate Log in Information

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'd like my Angular JS form to be able to confirm that someone's log in information is correct when it's typed into the input. Am I doing this right?

```
 HERE'S THE ANGULAR JS
var app= angular.module('multiPageApp', []);


//SET UP: Array of users

app.controller('logIn', function($scope){
  $scope.users = [
      {
        username: 'Regie',
        password: 'Tano'
      },
      {
        username: 'Jacob',
        password: 'Minshall'
      },
      {
        username: 'Greg',
        password: 'Mayer'
      }
    ]

  $scope.log = function(){
    //Get Values of Inputs for username and password
    var username= document.getElementById('input').value
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value

    //Loop through users to check if username and password are correct.
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      if(username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password){
        console.log('it worked!')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use angular $scope variables in order to get the input and password fields. 
You can define them associated to your inputs as below:

```
<input type="text" id="input" ng-model="username" placeholder="Type your username..." />
```

Then, you can use the JavaScript filter (or also find if you are using ECMA6) method in order to get the match:

```
if (users.filter(checkCredentials).length > 0) {
    // ok case.
}
else {
    // error case. Use ngMessages to show errors in the form
}

function checkCredentials(element) {
  return element.username === $scope.username && element.password === $scope.password;
}
```

Best way in angular to display error validation is using ngMessages:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-model to capture the value entered in textbox as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter username" />
<input type="password" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
```

And in your controller check in this way:

var app= angular.module('multiPageApp', []);

```
//SET UP: Array of users

app.controller('logIn', function($scope){
  $scope.users = [
      {
        username: 'Regie',
        password: 'Tano'
      },
      {
        username: 'Jacob',
        password: 'Minshall'
      },
      {
        username: 'Greg',
        password: 'Mayer'
      }
    ]

  $scope.log = function(){

    //Loop through users to check if username and password are correct.
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      if(username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password){
        console.log('it worked!')
      }
    }
  }
});
```